# I need to write a validation logic(using regex) for a particular enum type using spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, validation

Usecase

I have an enum named document-type which contains passport,PAN CARD.I want to validate the PAN card[length and character] using regex. How to implement that using spring boot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotation before variable:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}")
private String panCard;
```

or implement validation method:

```
public boolean isValidPanCard(String panCardNo) {
   String regex = "[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}";
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
   if (panCardNo == null) {
       return false;
   }
   Matcher m = p.matcher(panCardNo);
   return m.matches();
}
```

Comment: Document Type is enum and it contains values PAN_CARD and PASSPORT. Will @Pattern work here?

Comment: You right. It can not be like this. But I found sth what can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526449/how-to-get-regex-assigned-to-certain-enum